# Molecular Laser Isotope Separation for vapor $\rm H_2O$ and $\rm D_2O$ and why not implemented?

Tags: lasers, nuclear-engineering, nuclear-technology, evaporation

Based on the material from [The absorption spectra of liquid phase H2O, HDO and D2O from 0·7 μm to 10 μm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0020089163900265?via%3Dihub), where the IR absorption spectra of H20 and HDO are somewhat similar but noticeably different from D20, I believe a Molecular Laser Isotope Separation (MLIS) scheme might work well for the separation of deuterium by vaporization of water, and then laser emissions targeting absorption peaks for D2O only.

My question is this: why are such methods not used? I would like to know the potential downsides of using MLIS methods for Deuterium enrichment and other potential reasons why it may not be implemented yet.